# Can community user access the document folder object?

Tags: community, folder

I am not able to access the Document folder object when logged-in user is community user? The licence type is Customer Community.

Do we need to provide any special permission to access it?

Comment: Which community licence type are you using as there are different restrictions that apply based on that?

Comment: User License = Customer Community

Comment: Which Folders are you trying to access Document or Reports?

Comment: Type = Document

Answer (score 0):

As Dave has pointed out, Reports and Dashboards tabs are exposed in the community, external users can access reports and dashboards with some limitations.

Check [Communities Report and Dashboard Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_communities_analytics.htm)

You can give permission to create and edit reports to communities users with the following licenses:

**Community licenses**

- Customer Community Plus
- Customer Community Plus Login
- Partner Community
- Partner Community Login

Portal licenses

- Customer Portal Manager
- Customer Portal Manager Custom (for Enterprise Administration users)
- Customer Portal Manager Standard
- Customer Portal Manager User
- Gold Partner
- Ideas Only Portal
- Overage Customer Portal Manager Custom
- Overage Customer Portal Manager Standard
- Partner
- Silver Partner (”Export Reports” permission isn’t available to this
  license)

These permissions aren’t available to high-volume user licenses, such as Customer Community, High Volume Customer Portal, Service Cloud Portal, and Authenticated Website.
External users with legacy portal licenses can create and edit reports in communities, but not in portals.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to share Document folders to Customer Community users, the settings are done on each individual folder. If the folder needs to be accessible to all users you can give Public Read or Public Read/Write permissions here. Assigning access to community users will use the Portal Users option if you do not want to use global permissions for it.

You will need to make the tab accessible to the Customer Community users in their profile.

The Customer Community users will only ever have [Read permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) due to their licence type.

[image]